# Angular - CSS loaded delayed inside of app-root

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to implement an animation on app start inside of `<app-root>...</app-root>`. Therefore I've done the following:

```
<app-root>
    <style>
      h1 {
        font-family: 'Calibre Medium';
        color: black;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
      }
    </style>

    <h1>Test</h1>

</app-root>
```

It's being displayed, but its CSS is loaded delayed, hence the font is different initially and changes after about 1 sec.

Is there a way to improve this or another approach to implement such behavior?

EDIT: I've already tried to load style inside of the docs head and `style.css` - no difference.

EDIT: I'm using bootstrap - could this cause a problem?

Comment: then try inline style. It is not elegant but maybe it will solve your issue...

Answer (score 1):

humm... why the `style` tags inside `app-root` ? is this a requirement ? if not, try this instead :

```
<head>
    //...
  <style>
    #my-beautiful-loader {
      font-family: 'Calibre Medium';
      color: black;
      font-size: 2rem;
      margin: 0;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

//...
<app-root>

    <h1 id="my-beautiful-loader">Test</h1>

</app-root>
```

This **should** load the css before displaying your h1 tag

Bonus: [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zffbfg?file=src/index.html)

Comment: The content inside of app-root is for initial loading stuff, but the style stuff should be in document head as you show, +1

Comment: yep Christ, I was refering to the style tag. I should have explain that better :)

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, if you want to add global styles, you can add it to your `angular.json` file.

**src/styles.css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Calibre Medium;
  src: url(/* path to your fonts file */) format(/* fonts file format */);
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Calibre Medium';
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

See [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) for `font-face` src format options.

**angular.json**

```
...
  "styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
  ],
...
```

This will load your css when your application starts exactly as if you have added them as a `<link>` tag or a `<style>` tag in your `index.html`. (See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles))

Comment: It is still loaded delayed. Bootstrap classes are delayed as well.

Comment: There could be something else at play here. Where are you loading your font from? The issue could be the font itself. Can you change the color to yellow or something and see if the css itself gets applied and whether it's just the font that's causing the issue?

Comment: Yellow f.e. is being loaded immediately, but nearly every other style, as well with the bootstrap classes are being loaded delayed.

Comment: Where are you loading your custom font and bootstrap in your application?

Comment: Both are being imported to angular.json - I have a separate font.scss

Comment: You're right, I tried a preinstalled font and it worked fine (bootstrap still delayed tho) - how can I bypass this?

Comment: Try loading the fonts at the start of your ````styles.css````. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately there's still a delay for bootstrap.